# Integrate Woocommerce to a custom theme

Tags: customization, themes, woocommerce-offtopic

I have created a custom theme. Now I want to add WooCommerce to that theme but it doesn't work like the way it should.

After install of the WooCommerce plugin I followed all provided steps.
All pages needed are created and I have added my first product.

In the admin panel I get the message:

> Your theme does not declare woocommerce support

In the same message is a link to a WooCommerce page that tells you how to fix it.
https://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

So I did this and my page template fort WooCommerce now looks like this:

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: WooCommerce
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="cc_sbr">
    <div class="c1_sbr">
        <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It is called `woocommerce.php`

In my `functions.php` I have added `add_theme_support('woocommerce');`

So now my "store" page gives me the following:
Title: Shop
Content: Only result

But no content.

Can anyone help me by telling me what I do wrong or am missing?

M.

Answer (score 1):

Oke found it....

You (I) have to update the permalinks settings.

There is a shoppart added to the default page. 
select the custom part and add the name of your shop page starting with a `/`
e.g. `/shop`

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your theme functions.php

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
    function woocommerce_support() {
        add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
    }